# why does repoquery output wrong file list?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

On my YUM server I have this RPM ...

```
redcricket@rpo-dev:/usr/RED/docs/yum/CEL6/RIE$ rpm -q --filesbypkg -p development/RPMS/ooo-audit-1.0-10.noarch.rpm 
ooo-audit                 /apps/RED/red_apps/server/ooo-audit.pl
```

... and I have it installed on my system and rpm says this about that RPM ...

```
[redcricket@dev-006 src]$ rpm -q --filesbypkg ooo-audit
ooo-audit                 /apps/RED/red_apps/server/ooo-audit.pl
```

... but repoquery list the files on the old version of the RPM ...

```
[redcricket@dev-006 src]$ repoquery -l ooo-audit
/apps/RED/data/ooo-audit/exceptions.txt
/apps/RED/red_apps/server/ooo-audit.pl
```

... even after I do a "sudo yum clean all" ...

```
[redcricket@dev-006 src]$ sudo yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, merge-conf
Cleaning repos: ...
Cleaning up Everything
```

... see ...

```
[redcricket@dev-006 src]$ repoquery -l ooo-audit
/apps/RED/data/ooo-audit/exceptions.txt
/apps/RED/red_apps/server/ooo-audit.pl
```

here's the yum-utils I have installed ....

```
[redcricket@dev-006 src]$ rpm -q yum-utils
yum-utils-1.1.30-10.el6.noarch
```

... what's going on here?
The yum confs are correct. The RPM ooo-audit is only available on my YUM server, rpo-dev.
I have also updated the repodata on the YUM server. Should I report a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the YUM repository data itself is incorrect, which is an independent database on the YUM server from the RPM database. Based on your username and the example path, I am assuming it is your own yum server and custom repo; you need to re-run `makerepo` or whatever command you used to import the RPMs into the YUM repo.

(I will even guess that an older version of the `ooo-audit` package had that other file in it when the repo was created.)